# Condition with User property not affect on Remote Config of Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config

I have a User Property: **Max_Level_Completed** mean max level user completed.
I used it as a Condition of Remote Config Firebase: **Max_Level_Completed >= 10**
Users have Max_Level_Completed >= 10 will have a sale-off.

But when users have **Max_Level_Completed >= 10**, I still can't fetch new config for these users.
If I clear app data, I can fetch new config.

What is problems here?
And how can I fetch new data as soon as user have **Max_Level_Completed >= 10**?

Answer (score 2):

> If I clear app data, I can fetch new config.

That leads me to believe that perhaps you're still seeing cached values when you're testing. This is normal -- by default, Remote Config will cache values for about 12 hours before trying to download new values from the service. (Scroll down to the "Let's talk about caching" section of [this blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/01/firebase-remote-config-loading.html) for more information.)

In a normal app, this should be fine. But if you're trying to test out remote config by reaching level 10 and then immediately restarting your app or something, you probably won't see the results you're expecting.

I would recommend either waiting a day after you reach level 10 to see if you're getting the correct remote config values, or temporarily turning on developer mode and decreasing the cache time just for testing purposes.